# I want to find the latest date in Excel for a particular item from the list of thousand of items

Tags: excel

[image]

So in the above example for the first item I want the latest date to be 17th July 2018.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**How To Ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section first! I'd also personally recommend [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)! Afterwards, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51266850/edit) your question accordingly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Office 365 use MAXIFS:

```
=MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,A2)
```

With Older USE AGGREGATE:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,$B$2:$B$20/($A$2:$A$20=A2),1)
```

Comment: I am using MS- office Professional-2016 & can't find out the MAXIFS function but the Aggregate one is Working. Thanks buddy for the help. Saves tons of my time. I was trying to crack it for sometime.

Comment: @sanjaygautam please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Done.One more question in the above question, if we have the month in place instead of date, say Jan-16, Feb-16.....Dec-16 which formula shall we use?

Answer (score 1):

For pre-xl2010 use a psuedo-MAXIFS.

```
=MAX(INDEX($B$2:$B$20+($A$2:$A$20<>A2)*-1e99, , ))
```